# Filtering Soundcloud Tags with PHP

Tags: php, strpos

Soundcloud's API [returns a string of tags](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tag_list) for each track like so:

```
Pop Rock "Soft Pop" "Soft Rock" "Easy Listening" Jazz
```

where the string contains a list of tags seperated by spaces. Multiword tags are quoted in doublequotes.

At first, I was using something like

```
$tracktags = 'Pop Rock "Soft Pop" "Soft Rock" "Easy Listening" Jazz';
if(strpos($tracktags, "Soft Rock") !== false) {
    //we found a match
}
```

To find all songs that are `Soft Rock`.

This becomes cumbersome when I am trying to narrow down tracks that include this 1 term when some of these terms include words being used in other tags.

So, for example if that tag I was looking for was `Pop`, using this method I get songs that are tagged `Soft Pop`, `Country Pop`, `Pop ballads`, and so on, because using `strpos()` just finds that part of the string .  That's not the result I am hoping for; in this instance I just want to get songs that are tagged `Pop`.

I am thinking I need to separate this string into an array and then cycle through the array to make sure each value is implicitly identical to the tag I am searching for... but I'm not sure how I would do that.  I guess `split()` by the quotations, then `split()` the remaining by spaces?

Is there a PHP function that can compare both the string and length of the string, I guess, to ensure it is identical to my searching term?

Comment: I think the best way to go is though regular expressions and parsing all tags in a PHP array... I'll come back here later and answer it if no one answers until that.

Comment: If you have a one word search term, "pop", you could first filter out the ones with Quotes that define a multiword tag. I think a Regular Expression is going to help better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting into an array using `str_getcsv()` with a space as the delimiter. It will use the quotes as enclosures by default and will ignore the space inside the quotes. Then just use `in_array()`:

```
$tracktags = str_getcsv($tracktags, ' ');

if(in_array('Pop', $tracktags)) {
    //we found a match
}
```

To see what's there:

```
print_r($tracktags);
```

Comment: Couldn't have been a more perfect solution for not only how to split the array with double quotes and spaces, but also how to check the array for a specific term which may be paired with another term within the same array.  Thanks @AbraCadaver!!